# TRI - utilizando MIRT

Tags: r

Estou aplicando o TRI (Teoria de Resposta ao Item) com o pacote `mirt`, no RStudio. Porém, ao aplicar o `mirt`, o processamento interrompe quando atinge 500 iterações. É possível aumentar o número de iterações? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 3):

O número máximo de iterações está documentado na página de ajuda do pacote, função `mirt`.

De `help("mirt")`.

> technical
>
> ```
>     a list containing lower level technical parameters for  
>     estimation. May be:  
>
> NCYCLES maximum number of EM or MH-RM cycles;  
>         defaults are 500 and 2000
> ```

Tradução Google Translate.

> technical
>
> ```
>    uma lista contendo parâmetros técnicos de nível inferior  
>    para estimação. Talvez:  
>
> NCYCLES  número máximo de ciclos EM ou MH-RM;  
>    os padrões são 500 e 2000
> ```

Testando com um dos exemplos que não converge com o número de iterações padrão, o exemplo com o conjunto de dados `SAT12`, vê-se que funciona.

```
library(mirt)

data(SAT12)
data <- key2binary(SAT12,
                   key = c(1,4,5,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,4,2,1,5,3,4,4,1,4,3,3,4,1,3,5,1,3,1,5,4,5))

mod2 <- mirt(data, 2, optimizer = 'NR')
#Iteration: 500, Log-Lik: -9441.963, Max-Change: 0.00012
#EM cycles terminated after 500 iterations.

mod2.b <- mirt(data, 2, optimizer = 'NR', 
             technical = list(NCYCLES = 5000))
#Iteration: 1065, Log-Lik: -9441.950, Max-Change: 0.00010
```

Neste segundo caso foi até à iteração `1065` e atingiu a tolerância `0.0001`.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Answer (score 1):

Trazendo a tradução da resposta que achei num Google Groups:

"Está na lista técnica de entrada, chamada NCYCLES:

```
mod <- mirt(Science, 1, technical = list(NCYCLES = 2000))
```

fonte:[Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mirt-package/5JT8IWas7PI)

Comment: Muito obrigada!!